# Поиск текста в таблицах импортируемых из Excel документов

Tags: php, javascript, wordpress

Подскажите как реализовать текстовый поиск в таблицах, которые загружались на сайт импортом из документов Excel через сайт плагин (сайт работает на WordPress). Например, я импортировал на страничку три больших Excel таблицы. В каждой из таблиц имеется столбик с артикулами товаров. Я хотел бы реализовать поиск, в котором при вводе определённого числа (артикула) выдаёт все строчки из трёх таблиц, в которых упоминается данное число. Может быть я использую, мало функциональный плагин для импорта, возможно Вы подскажете более мощный, в котором уже есть данные функции.

Comment: а может лучше попробовать пойти другим путем?! создать табличку в бд, при сохранении файла на сервер делать импорт в эту таблицу и поиск уже делать в ней.

Comment: Большое спасибо за ответ, А как это реализовать, может подскажете статью какую нить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По большому счету, никакой альтернативы [Phpexcel](https://phpexcel.codeplex.com/) у вас нет, если делать действительно хорошо.

Но если хочется что-то быстро набросать, то попробуйте плагин [WP Excel CMS](http://tanyamaliy.com/blog/wp-admin/plugin-install.php?tab=plugin-information&plugin=wp-excel-cms&TB_iframe=true&width=600&height=550)

Comment: С помощью плагина не получиться. В таблице 148 000 строк, переписывался даже напрямую с разработчиком, он сказал, что через плагин не получиться, не те объемы информации.

Comment: Ну, с таким объемом информации и Phpexcel нельзя просто так напрямую использовать (три посетителя, и серверу каюк). Как советовал Bald56rus, делать табличку в БД и работать с ней.
Вообще, пришел в голову Workaround: вам надо найти плагин, который делает то, что вам нужно с какими-то товарами, храня их в базе. Вы же в эту базу заливаете свои Excel по совету s976 через `.csv` с помощью `Phpmyadmin`, который обычно есть на хостинге.

Answer (score 1):

Очень просто.
Файлы Экселя нужно сохранить как `.csv`.
Теперь это простой текстовый файл. Можно загрузить его содержание в массив используя функцию `[str_getcsv][1]`. Ну а дальше все тривиально.

Замечу, что более верный подход - записывать все данные в БД (как верно заметил Bald56rus).

Comment: Большое спасибо за ответ, А как это реализовать, может подскажете статью какую нить?

Comment: @ВалерийЕмельянов Трудно сказать. Поскольку это зависит об объема уже имеющихся у Вас навыков и знаний. Если Вы не пишите коды на PHP, то я вообще не знаю как объяснить. А если пишите - может начните что-нибудь и скажите в чем затрудняетесь. По большому счету Вам нужно написать функцию, которая принимает входное значение, открывает файл, записывает его в массив, делает поиск по массиву, выдает нужную строку из файла.

Comment: Нет, я не пишу коды php :((